# Fade in / out Menu

Tags: jquery, menu, fadein, fadeout

I'm using the following jQuery code to create a fade in-fade and fade-out effect when users hover over an unordered menu list. I can't seem to get the fade to work however. Any help would be most appreciated.

Here is a link to an online test page:
http://www.youmeusdesign.co.uk/menutest/

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$(function(){
    $("#menu ul li").hover(function(){
             $(this).children("ul").fadeIn(500);
       },
       function(){
             $(this).children("ul").fadeOut(500);   
    })
})
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li aria-haspopup="true"><a href="index.html"></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">ABOUT</a>
                    <ul class="submenu1">
                        <li class="column1" aria-haspopup="false"><a href="index.html">Approach</a></li>
                        <li class="column1" aria-haspopup="false"><a href="index.html">Team</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>    
                <li><a href="index.html">CASE STUDIES</a>
                    <ul class="submenu2">
                        <li class="column1" aria-haspopup="false">TITLE1</li>
                        <li class="column1" aria-haspopup="false"><a href="index.html">Project A</a></li>
                        <li class="column1" aria-haspopup="false"><a href="index.html">Project B</a></li>
                        <li class="column1" aria-haspopup="false"><a href="index.html">Project C</a></li>
                        <li class="column1" aria-haspopup="false"><a href="index.html">Project D</a></li>
                        <li class="column1" aria-haspopup="false"><a href="index.html">Project E</a></li>
                        <li class="column1" aria-haspopup="false"><a href="index.html">Project F</a></li>
                        <li class="column1" aria-haspopup="false"><a href="index.html">Project G</a></li>
                        <li class="column2 negative-margin-160" aria-haspopup="false">TITLE2</li>
                        <li class="column2" aria-haspopup="false"><a href="index.html">Project H</a></li>
                        <li class="column2" aria-haspopup="false"><a href="index.html">Project I</a></li>
                        <li class="column2" aria-haspopup="false"><a href="index.html">Project J</a></li>
                        <li class="column2" aria-haspopup="false"><a href="index.html">Project K</a></li>
                        <li class="column2" aria-haspopup="false"><a href="index.html">Project L</a></li>
                        <li class="column2" aria-haspopup="false"><a href="index.html">Project M</a></li>
                        <li class="column2" aria-haspopup="false"><a href="index.html">Project N</a></li>
                        <li class="column2" aria-haspopup="false"><a href="index.html">Project O</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="index.html">NEWS &amp; PRESS</a>
                    <ul class="submenu3">
                        <li class="column1" aria-haspopup="false"><a href="index.html">News</a></li>
                        <li class="column1" aria-haspopup="false"><a href="index.html">Press</a></li>
                        <li class="column1" aria-haspopup="false"><a href="index.html">Awards</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li> 
                <li><a href="index.html">CONTACT</a>
                </li>       
            </ul>
        </li>       
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Code looks fine at first glance. What's the problem?

Comment: Works for me in Chrome.

Comment: Strange. You are all right works in Chrome and Firefox but for some reason does not work in Safari?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running into a conflict between your CSS and your Javascript. In your CSS, you have this:

```
#menu ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 545px;
    height: 270px;
    left: 0;
    top: 80px;
    display: none;
    padding-top: 20px;
    background: #CCC;
}
```

And then when you hover over one of the li elements, your CSS does this:

```
#menu ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    background-image: none;
}
```

Your Javascript is trying to fade the element in, but it's too late—at that point, the element has already been set to `display: block` by the CSS. When you hover off, jQuery adds an inline style to the `#menu ul li ul` element, setting `opacity: 0`.

The next time you hover onto the element, even though CSS is setting the element to `display: block`, the elements remain hidden because they are inlined as `opacity: 0`, letting them fade in as you want.

The quickest fix is to set the opacity to 0 in the CSS for `#menu ul ul`, though I am curious about why .fadeIn() didn't work for you.

Comment: Thanks that worked really well. will investigate further about the .fadeIn.

Answer (score 0):

Work in Firefox but doesn't work in chrome use aminate or show/hide

Comment: Why would .fadeIn() fail in Safari/Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments. Have tried using animate and it's now working in Chrome and Safari, however the fade does not seem to work the first time you hover over the menu after the page loads and you have to re-hover the second time to get it working:

Here is a link to a modified online test page: http://www.youmeusdesign.co.uk/menutest/

here is the modified jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $("#menu ul li").hover(function(){
             $(this).children("ul").animate(
            {"opacity": "1"},
            500);
       },
       function(){
             $(this).children("ul").animate(
            {"opacity": "0"},
            500);   
    })
})
```

Many thanks.